# Memory leak while caching in foreachBatch block in Spark structured streaming app

Tags: apache-spark, memory-leaks, spark-structured-streaming

We have a structured streaming application, and we face a memory leak while caching in the `foreachBatch` block.

We do unpersist every iteration, and we also verify via `spark.sparkContext.getPersistentRDDs` that we don't have unnecessary cached data.

We also noted in the profiler that many sparkSession objects are created while we use cache (vs 2 sparkSession objects while not using cache).

Any idea what can cause this? We use spark 3.1.1 running on AKS

Answer (score 0):

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-35262

This has fixed at spark 3.2.0

Comment: Link-only answers have risk of link going dead. Please consider providing summary/steps from link to solve the problem.